# Different ways of picking sets producing different results?

Tags: combinatorics

We were asked to count the number of possible sets with 4 elements (4-sets), picked from the integers $ \{1,2...,10\} $, without replacements, such that the set contains at least one integer $\le4$.

First, I picked one integer $\le4$, ${4 \choose 1}$, and then I picked the other 3 numbers, ${9 \choose 3}$ (because once you have the required integer $\le4$, you can select from the remaining set of integers).  So the total number of 4-sets would be ${4 \choose 1}{9 \choose 3} = 336 $.

However, the right way I saw to count the sets was to partition the sets  into how many sets contained one integer $\le4$, then two integers $\le4$, then three, then four.$${4 \choose 1}{6 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}+{4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1}+{4 \choose 4}{6 \choose 0} = 195$$

There's obviously a difference in the two results but I'm not sure why my reasoning/method is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have explained your reasoning very clearly. This makes it easier to discuss the issue.

The problem with your analysis is *multiple counting*.

When you "first"  pick a number $\le 4$, it might be $2$, and then later you might pick $4, 5,7$. But that gives the same result as picking $4$ "first" and then $2,5,7$. These are counted a different picks by your product.

So this particular choice of $4$ numbers is double-counted. Some sets of $4$, such as $\{1,2,3,10\}$ are triple-counted by your product.  And $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is quadruple-counted. Only sets that have exactly one number $\le 4$ are single-counted.

**Remark**: Sometimes one can deliberately multiple-count, and then adjust to take care of the multiple-counting. This can be a useful strategy. That is not very useful here, because the degree of multiple counting varies.